# Outlook mails using SMTP with Python

Tags: python, mime, smtplib

Please can someone show how to you use MS Outlook mails with python. Sending mails. I tried using MIME and SMTPLIB but i get authentication failed at server.login()

Although I am entering correctly.

What I am missing please?

This is my organisation outlook mail , and I need to shoot a mail to my org mail baox using python.

Comment: It is very likely that your organization does not permit access to the Exchange email message store except via authorized applications, in other words Outlook itself. You can discuss this with your sysops but I suspect they will be unsympathetic.

Comment: Okay . Thanks. I will check if its possible with my IT .